# Why can't I add width and height to my div using javascript on html dom

Tags: javascript, html, css, simple-html-dom

So I am playing around with one of the challenge some one ask me to do: to draw  squares inside one each other but the inner squares must have a side half of the immediate outer square and they must center

This is the code I wrote so far :

```
(function(){
    var width=200;
    var bodyEle=document.getElementById('result');
    while(width>2){
    var square =document.createElement('div');

        square.style.width =width+'px';
        square.style.height =width+'px';
        square.setAttribute('style','border:2px solid black');
        width=width/2;
        bodyEle.appendChild(square);

    }
}());
```

The problem is the divs don't seem to take the width I give them  .

Also this is one of way I tried to do this, I am pretty sure this is not the best way , if you guys have a way to achieve the same but in an elegant way please share

https://jsfiddle.net/op22uLug/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: `div` is a block-level element, so it will span the full with by default.
Second: after setting the width/height style, you overrided it in `square.setAttribute('style','border:2px solid black');`

The correct code would be:

```
(function(){
  var width=200;
  var bodyEle=document.getElementById('result');
  while(width>2){
    var square =document.createElement('div');

    square.style.width =width+'px';
    square.style.height =width+'px';
    square.style.display = 'inline-block';
    square.style.border = '2px solid black';
    //square.setAttribute('style','border:2px solid black');
    width=width/2;
    bodyEle.appendChild(square);
  }
}());
```

Comment: yes it works,ty , also I am trying to center is now I have margin 0 auto ,but it doesn't seem to work , any quick pointers why so.. https://jsfiddle.net/op22uLug/4/

Comment: What's the purpose of `square.style.display = 'inline-block';` there ?

Comment: oh so it is like float but on blocks, I reset  it to  display block ,it did center horizontally but vertically it is still still on the top :(

https://jsfiddle.net/op22uLug/5/

Comment: Vertical centering is whole different problem though. You should learn more about CSS layouts, and/or [flexbox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/)

Comment: yes I was searching a bit one of the solution is verticalAlign attribute but the more generic one is using relative position and top , in %

Thanks for your responses :)